# How to open URL with scheme intent:// on react native

Tags: react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a react native mobile app with a webview. In the webview I added the facebook messenger chat plugin so my users can easily contact us if they need help.

if you ran the website through a mobile browser it works. It redirects you to the official messenger.

But when you ran it through react native webview somehow it says No activity found to handle Intent

here is my code on how i handle the opening of the intent

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(request) => {
    let url = request.url   

    if(url.startsWith('intent:')){
          Linking.openURL(url).catch(er => {
              console.log(er)
              alert("Failed to open URL")
          });

          return false
    }else{
        return true
    }   
}}
```

this will console log

> [Error: Could not open URL
> 'intent://user/107571147455693/?intent_trigger=mme&nav=discover&source=customer_chat_plugin&source_id=1507329&metadata=%7B%22referer_uri%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffusiontechph.com%5C%2Ff9fe1863270a2%22%7D#Intent;scheme=fb-messenger;package=com.facebook.orca;end':
> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> dat=intent://user/107571147455693/?intent_trigger=mme&nav=discover&source=customer_chat_plugin&source_id=1507329&metadata={"referer_uri":"https://fusiontechph.com/f9fe1863270a2"}
> flg=0x10000000 }]