# React Native: Can't open url: intent://

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, nemlogin

The Danish national 2FA service MitId recently got a bit of an update, which has messed up app switching on our React Native app.

I'm running a website in a `WebView` which as part of the expected behaviour needs to open the MitId 2FA app to perform authentication.

However, when I try doing this on Android (iOS works fine), I get the following error:

`Can't open url: intent://appswitchmitid.page.link/?link=https://appswitch.mitid.dk?ticket%<long string of hexadecimal numbers here>%26returnUrl%3DChrome&apn=dk.mitid.app.android&afl=https://appswitch.mitid.dk#Intent;package=com.google.android.gms;action=com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.VIEW_DYNAMIC_LINK;scheme=https;S.browser_fallback_url=https://appswitch.mitid.dk;end;`

I'm not super familiar with the inner workings fot he intent bus on Android, so I'm mostly looking for guidance to figure out exactly what I'm supposed to do with this URL so that I can dispatch the app switching myself.

PS: I am aware of this question: [How to open URL with scheme intent:// on react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345797/how-to-open-url-with-scheme-intent-on-react-native)

It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebViews are not supported anymore on Android, you should change your implementation to use Custom Tabs instead.

From Signaturgruppen's own technical reference:

> Embedded browsers, i.e.WebViews, are not supported and not allowed – thus integrations must adhere strictly using to the Android Custom
> Tabs (Chrome or Samsung browser) or iOS SFSafariViewController (TAB)
> for all MitID integration flows. MitID requires that the address bar
> is visible, such that the end-user can see the https and MitID domain
> when authenticating with MitID. Android Custom Tabs:
> https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/ iOS
> SFSafariViewController:
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller

**You can read about the new requirements here:**
https://broker.signaturgruppen.dk/application/files/1816/8742/0440/Nets_eID_Broker_MitID_mobile_app_integration_v2.5.pdf

Comment: Hi Electric Coffee, did you ever get the setup to work? I'm having trouble with the app switch :)

Comment: I'm using this package which works fine on iOS and some android devices
https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser.

However we are having trouble on some android devices where we are stucked on the mitID login screen. A workaround for the users is to click on the back button - but it really sucks that the flow is not completed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I eventually got it to work in a Flutter application.

I'm not sure that I have any valid input to the problem you are facing, as i'm not sure where in the flow you are stuck. Do you use a backend to signal the app to close the inappbrowser after verification?